# How to access the objective c protocol from swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, ios9

Objective C class
In Header File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ResponseDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)serverResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseData;

@end

@interface KKHttpClient : NSObject<NSURLSessionDataDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate>

@property(weak, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary *responseData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ResponseDelegate>responseDelegate;

-(void)connectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url withData:(NSData *)params;

@end
```

In Implementation File

```
#import "KKHttpClient.h"
#import "KKOTPViewController.h"
#import "QuikCatalog-swift.h"

NSMutableData *receivedData;

@implementation KKHttpClient

-(void)connectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url withData:(NSData *)params
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
    NSData *postData = params;
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        if (!error)
        {
            NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
            self.responseData = response;
        }
        if ([self.responseDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serverResponse:)])
        {
            [self.responseDelegate serverResponse:self.responseData];
            NSLog(@"responseData:%@", self.responseData);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
@end
```

Swift Class

```
import UIKit

@objc class InviteesViewController: UIViewController, Dimmable ,ResponseDelegate {

    func getInviteeData(){
        let myClass : KKHttpClient = KKHttpClient()
        myClass.responseDelegate = self
        let stringUrl = "http://52.34.224.26:1337/qc/getInvitee"
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:stringUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!)!
        let parameters: NSString  = "{\"rqBody\":{\" \": \"\"}}"
        print(parameters)
        let postData:NSData = parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        print(postData)
        myClass.connectWithUrl(url, withData: postData)
    }

    func serverResponse(responseData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        print(responseData)
        let rsBody = responseData

    }
}
```

I get succeeded to call the server through My Swift Class function with the use of Objective class
but I don't get the response data in my swift class function
though I get the response from the server in my objective C class but did get the data in my function...

Plzz. suggest where i m lacking
My response Data is

```
rsBody =     (
{
    createdAt = "2016-04-27T05:48:51.708Z";
    id = 572052c325a4e37e2180450e;
    invitedById = 571e136005229e2f024320c7;
    inviteeCreationDate = 1461736131673;
    inviteeEmail = "a@b.com";
    inviteeMobile = 9999999997;
    inviteeName = kunal;
    inviteeStatus = "ON_HOLD";
    role = CUSTOMER;
    updatedAt = "2016-04-27T05:48:51.708Z";
}

{
    createdAt = "2016-04-27T05:48:51.708Z";
    id = 572052c325a4e37e2180450e;
    invitedById = 571e136005229e2f024320c7;
    inviteeCreationDate = 1461736131673;
    inviteeEmail = "a@b.com";
    inviteeMobile = 9999999997;
    inviteeName = kunal;
    inviteeStatus = "ON_HOLD";
    role = CUSTOMER;
    updatedAt = "2016-04-27T05:48:51.708Z";
}
);
```

and also suggest how to parse the response in swift class... with some code example.

Comment: First step will be [bridge objective-c to swift](https://github.com/jeevanRao7/swiftbridge)

Comment: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/ <= try this.

Comment: I already created bridge header... and import my objective c header file..@jeevan

Comment: Well `myClass` is a local variable and the object will be destroyed when `getInviteeData()` returns, not giving it chance to finish.  To parse that data use the `NSJSONSerializion` class.  I am also suspicious how this question got 3 upvotes as it contains beginner mistakes and shows no effort at all.  Who is upvoting this crap?

Comment: I got this response data in my objective c class that i have showed above, by calling objective C class from my swift class ,there i used the NSJSONSerialization for getting the response , now  i m using objective c protocol in my swift class for getting this response but  i m not getting the response in my swift class..   @trojanfoe